# IPython Notebook controls

Tags: angularjs, ipython, jupyter-notebook

All. We are going to use IPython NB in our project and we need to inject IPython NB controls into our UI. We will use it together with angularjs. I was trying to find any documentation about how does IpythonNB UI work, but I have find only general information. Could anybody help me with this? I need to know how I could intercept NB controls (like save, run etc). It's also will be nice If you could redirect me to correct contacts.

Comment: Please ask on github and/or IPython mailing list we can help you there.

Comment: Hi, Matt. Thanks for answer. Do you mean ipython-dev@scipy.org?

Comment: Yes, IPython-dev@scipy.org would be fine. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jupyter would be fine also.